# Is there a program like Python Tutor for C code?

Tags: c

There is this site (http://pythontutor.com) where you can input a Python code, and it'll say what each line of code does.

I was wondering, is there a program like Python Tutor, but for C code?

Comment: http://codepad.org/ is an online C compiler.

Comment: This is a very constructive question.  I had never heard of pythontutor and I found it amazing.  If there is something like this for C code, I would like to know.  If the question were "what is the best program...", it would create debate, but this is strictly factual.  Vote to reopen?

Comment: Since it needs to trace everything, it would be difficult to do in C code. Forks have been created for Java, JS and Ruby however.

Comment: Try Cloud9 it supports a lot of languages inc C https://c9.io/

Comment: Python Tutor now has [C Tutor - Visualize C code execution to learn C online](http://pythontutor.com/c.html#mode=edit).

Comment: I'm still looking for alternative of pythontutor